# How to extract multiple values from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a long Python list like:

```
['A p=45 n=200 SNR=12', 'B p=2232 n=22 SNR=2']
```

I would like to get from this list a list of tuples containing the value of `p`, `n` and `SNR`.

So:

```
funz(['A p=45 n=200 SNR=12', 'B p=2232 n=22 SNR=2'])
```

would return:

```
[(45,200,12), (2232,22,2)]
```

The strings in the list have all the same structure.

Comment: How far along are you in writing the solution yourself? Where are you stuck? :)

Comment: `[tuple(int(m) for m in re.findall(r'(\d+)', i)) for i in lst]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

data =  ['A p=45 n=200 SNR=12', 'B p=2232 n=22 SNR=2']

result = []

for x in data:
    result.append( map( int, re.search('p=(\d+).*n=(\d+).*SNR=(\d+)', x).groups()) )

print result

[[45, 200, 12], [2232, 22, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is this:

```
def funz(l):
    return [tuple(int(i.split('=')[1]) for i in item.split(' ')[1:]) for item in l]
```

Edited re @bvukelic's comment.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. Just do this, though: `int(i.split('=')[1])` OP wants ints. And yeah, the left-most comprehension should be wrapped in `tuple()` for completeness.

Comment: @bvukelic they also aparently want tuples

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> lst = ['A p=45 n=200 SNR=12', 'B p=2232 n=22 SNR=2']
>>> def funz(lst):
...     return [tuple(map(int, findall("\d+", i))) for i in lst]
...
>>> funz(['A p=45 n=200 SNR=12', 'B p=2232 n=22 SNR=2'])
[(45, 200, 12), (2232, 22, 2)]
>>>
```

The Regex pattern `\d+` matches one or more digits.